# Backlit keyboard on T431s not working

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

New to askubuntu

I just installed `14.04` on a `Thinkpad T431s` and the backlit keyboard doesn't seem to be working even after pressing  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd> .

Is this an easy fix?  Could you explain the process to me as if I was five (I'm new to Ubuntu)

Anything is much appreciated

Comment: where are your parents!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe running the following commands should fix the issue.

First, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.

Next, type the following command in the terminal, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, type in your password when you are asked to do so and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> again.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, do the same for the next command and type <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept the changes so long as it doesn't mention **removing** anything:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors tp-smapi-dkms tpb
```

Finally, run the following command and follow the given on screen instructions (type yes and then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept each of the prompts):

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

You may need to reboot for the changes to take effect and you should also have more accurate hardware temperature readings as a side result.

Comment: Thank you!  Pressed Fn + Space and it lit right up.  Wheeh, thanks again.  Hopefully there are others who will benefit from this.